# Android intent-filter for mime-type on remote content

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to create one intent-filter so that all json documents from one particular host are matched. 
I cannot use a pathpattern as the relevant part is in the query and as far as I know and tested I cannot match on the query part. So my Idea was to match on the mime-type - but I struggle here. 
The URL returns the correct content-type - I checked with curl -I

```
➜  ~  curl  -s -I  "https://engelsystem.de/32c3/?p=shifts_json_export&key=c7caceaaXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" | grep Content
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But when I have:

```
android:mimeType="application/json"
```

or even

```
android:mimeType="application/*"
```

as intent-filter -> then there is no match no more

as requested the full intent-fiter:

```
    <activity android:name=".ImportKeyFromURL">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:mimeType="application/*"
                android:host="engelsystem.de"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: post the entire `<intent-filter>` please

Comment: "I cannot match on the query part" -- correct.

Comment: @DavidWasser added the full intent-filter